Lookback options - Floating strike
Let's take the case of a Lookback Floating Strike Call, European style, where the payoff is determined by max(0, S-M), where is M is the max value of the stock over the life of the option.
Am I right in assuming that this option value is always zero? As the strike will take the max value of the option and the only payoff possible at maturity are either zero or negative?
What are the most common Lookback traded OTC? Maybe more American rather European?
Thanks!

You are correct that that payoff is identically zero. I can't answer what the most common types are, but you could for example have a call where the payoff is determined by $S(T) - m(T)$, where $m(t)$ is the minimum value of $S$ observed -- this would give something of interest mathematically

Thanks Rylan. Indeed, with a min() instead of max(), the value of the option is positive.
